# How to extract reviewer's ratings from Yelp.

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, r

I am learning web scraping on my own and I am trying to scrap reviewer's ratings on Yelp as a practice. Typically, I can use CSS selector or XPath methods to select the contents I am interested in. However, those methods do not work for selecting reviewers' ratings. For instance, on the following page: https://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=0S6EI51ej5J7dgYz3-O0lA. The CSS selector for the first rating is '.stars_2'. However, if I use this selector in my RSelenium code as follows:

```
     ratings=remDr$findElements('css selector','.stars_2')

     ratings=unlist(lapply(ratings, function(x){x$getElementText()}))
```

I get NULL. I think the reason is that the rating is actually a image. I paste a small part of the page source here:

```
            <div class="review-content">
            <div class="review-content">
            <div class="biz-rating biz-rating-very-large clearfix">
            <div>        
            <div class="rating-very-large">
            <i class="star-img stars_2" title="2.0 star rating">
          <img alt="2.0 star rating" class="offscreen" height="303" src="//s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_styleguide/c2252a4cd43e/assets/img/stars/stars_map.png" width="84">
    </i>
</div>


    </div>
```

Basically, if I can extract the text from class="stat-img stars_2" or title="2.0 star rating" then I am good. Can anyone help me on this? Please, I really want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using regular expressions on the page's html, something like:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://www.yelp.com/user_details_reviews_self?userid=0S6EI51ej5J7dgYz3-O0lA'
>>> html = requests.get(url).text
>>> import re
>>> rating_pattern = re.compile(r'\d.\d star rating">')
>>> for rating in re.findall(rating_pattern, html):
...     print(rating)
...
2.0 star rating">
4.0 star rating">
5.0 star rating">
5.0 star rating">
5.0 star rating">
5.0 star rating">
5.0 star rating">
2.0 star rating">
4.0 star rating">
2.0 star rating">
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this satisfy?

```
source = driver.page_source  # gets page source of current page
images = source.split("<img")[1:]
for image in images:
    if "star rating" in image:
        rating = image.split('''alt="''')[1]
        rating = rating.split("star")[0]
        rating = float(rating)
        print rating
        break
```